# Matrix Algebra to trace workflow precedents

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

what I'm trying to achieve is the following. I have a production chain, say for example:

```
A and B are used to make C
C and D are used to make E
and E is used to make F
```

And I wanna know the direct and indirect inputs of F, which would be all the others.

So I built a Matrix of the direct inputs like the following. 1 means the letter in this column is a direct input for the letter of this row

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F
A 0  0  0  0  0  0
B 0  0  0  0  0  0
C 1  1  0  0  0  0
D 0  0  0  0  0  0
E 0  0  1  1  0  0
F 0  0  0  0  1  0
```

And I want to transform this matrix (perharps via matrices multiplication) in a matrix that contains all the inputs, both direct and indirect and the answer would be:

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F
A 0  0  0  0  0  0
B 0  0  0  0  0  0
C 1  1  0  0  0  0
D 0  0  0  0  0  0
E 1  1  1  1  0  0
F 1  1  1  1  1  0
```

Any thoughts on it ? any other approach is also valid, other than the matricial one. thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your matrix $M = (m_{ij})$, where $m_{ij} = 1$ if component $i$ is directly used in the production of component $j$. Now $M$ is the *adjacency matrix* of the directed graph where the vertices are the components and in which there is an edge from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$ if and only if $i$ is directly used in the production of $j$.

Consider the matrix $M^2 = (m^{(2)}_{ik})$. By the definition of matrix multiplication, we have

$$m^{(2)}_{ik} = \sum_{j=1}^n m_{ij}m_{jk}.$$

Therefore, $m_{ik}^{(2)}$ is the *number of components $j$ so that $i$ is directly used in the production of $j$ and $j$ is used in the production of $k$*. In the language of graph theory, it is the number of directed length-$2$ paths from $i$ to $j$.

Similarly, if we consider $M^r = (m_{ik}^{(r)})$, then we have

$$m_{ik}^{(r)} = \sum_{j_1,\ldots,j_{r-1} = 1}^n m_{ij_1}m_{j_1j_2}\cdots m_{j_{r-1}j_k},$$

which counts the number of $(r-1)$-tuples $(j_1,\ldots,j_{r-1})$ of components so that component $i$ is directly used in the production of component $j_1$, component $_1$ is directly used in the production of component $j_2$, and so on until component $j_{r-1}$ is used in the production of component $j_k$. In the language of graph theory, this is the number of length-$r$ paths from $i$ to $j$ in your directed graph.

So we have some intuition that raising $M$ to a high power will count increasingly long chains of production dependencies. However, there is a problem. Suppose component $1$ depends on component $2$, and component $2$ depends on component $3$. Then if we consider $M^2 = (m_{ij}^{(2)})$ again, we have $m^{(2)}_{31} = 1$, but $m^{(2)}_{21} = 0$. In other words, $M^2$ notices the path $3\to 2\to 1$, but it has "forgotten about" the path $2\to 1$! A way to solve this problem is to set $m_{ii} = 1$ for all $i$; i.e. saying that each component depends on itself. Then, in my simple example, we will have the "path" $2\to 2\to 1$, so there will be a length-$2$ "path" from $2$ to $1$, and we will have $m^{(21)}>0$.

So in summary, if you take your matrix, modified so as to have $1$s instead of zeroes on the diagonal, and then raise it to a high power (the $n$th power would be enough, since any path can have at most $n$ steps), then $M^n$ will have a nonzero entry in the $i,j$ place if and only if component $j$ depends at some stage on component $i$.

Note that this is ***not*** the most computationally-efficient algorithm to determine the quantity you seek (in fact it would be extremely inefficient!), but it is a method involving matrices!

Comment: Brilliant ! i can't thank you enough ! any thoughts on how to do that in excel ? it's for a final user, so ideally i'd need to execute in excel without any vba whatsoever ! thanks

Comment: Apparently Excel can handle matrix multiplication; see http://web.stanford.edu/~wfsharpe/mia/mat/mia_mat4.htm. Note that this matrix method is only appropriate for rather small numbers of components; it is not an efficient algorithm and will not scale well as the number of components increases. You might get better answers on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but rather some clarifications that cannot be formatted easily as a comment.

## 1st Question

What do you want to happen if some outputs share a common direct input? For example:
If A and B make D; A and C make E; D and E make F; we would have

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F
A 0  0  0  0  0  0
B 0  0  0  0  0  0
C 0  0  0  0  0  0
D 1  1  0  0  0  0
E 1  0  1  0  0  0
F 0  0  0  1  1  0
```

Then your output would be

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F
A 0  0  0  0  0  0
B 0  0  0  0  0  0
C 0  0  0  0  0  0
D 1  1  0  0  0  0
E 1  0  1  0  0  0
F X  1  1  1  1  0
```

My question is (look at the lower left-hand corner where you see an "X") do you want X=1 to just merely indicate that A was used at some point as a direct input; or do you want X=2 to indicate that A was used *twice* as a direct input (for making both D and E in this example)?

---

## 2nd Question

Can inputs be used multiple times during the course of a workflow to produce increasingly complex outputs? For example, is this situation below valid:

A and B make E; C and D make F; A and E make G; etc.

Notice that A was used twice here to make G (once with B to make E; a second time with E to make G). Can A be used twice in this manner?

Comment: about question 2: if possible yes. if necessary we can assume that it can't and work the rest out.

Comment: sorry. about the frist question I'd like X to be 1. I just want to know whether it was used. But if by any chance it's easier to calculate it as being 2 it would be just as good !